# ThreadDelay Outside the Main Thread

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I've been trying to write a function that prints out a string letter by letter, without       quotes, and pauses for a little in between each letter. For example, if you give it "hello", it'll print h, then wait, the e, then wait, then l, then wait, then l, then wait, the o. But when i try to use `threadDelay`, it pauses in the main thread. So it'll pause, then print everything all at once. I tried to fork a new thread in the `prints` function, but it doesn't work. Help!

```
import Control.Concurrent as C

clean :: String -> String
clean s@[c]               = s
clean ('"':s)  
    | last s == '"'       = init s
    | otherwise           = s
clean ('\'':s) 
    | last s == '\''      = init s           
    | otherwise           = s
clean s                   = s

prints :: String -> IO()
prints [] = putStrLn " "
prints (x:xs) = do
    C.forkIO $ do
        putStr $ clean (show x)
        C.threadDelay $ 10000
        prints xs  

main :: IO()
main = do 
    prints "hello"
```

Comment: The following works for me: `prints = sequence_ . intersperse (threadDelay (10^5)) . map (putStr . return); main = hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering >> prints "hello"`.

Comment: @user2407038 : what platform?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Windows and Mac (in a vm but that shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 4):

Your code has a few problems.

Firstly, [`threadDelay`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent.html#v%3athreadDelay) takes an argument in *microseconds*, so the pause you are adding is too small to notice. Try `1000000`.

Secondly, unless you turn off buffering on `stdout`, the IO library will buffer up your output so you won't see it with the expected delays. You can control this with [`System.IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#12):

```
import System.IO ( stdout, hSetBuffering, BufferMode(..) )
```

and then call `hSetBuffering` from `main`:

```
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

Finally, forking off a thread is actually a step backwards, because the program doesn't wait for the forked threads to finish, so just remove that. If you really want it to be in the background, you'll need to use an `MVar` or similar to wait for it to finish if the program will otherwise naturally exit first.

Comment: Does it work if you use a delay of one million as I suggested, rather than one hundred thousand as I think you have? I can just about see it going slowly with one hundred thousand, but it's close to the limit of what a human can perceive. What you have is exactly what I tested with other than that difference.

Comment: No, it just pauses for a long time before, then prints everything out at once.

Comment: Here's my code in case I forgot any other difference: http://lpaste.net/106474 It definitely pauses for a second between each character on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Does adding `hFlush stdout` after the `putStr` help (you'll need to also import `hFlush` from `System.IO`)? I have no idea what's going on though, so just suggesting random things...